# Analytics E-commerce items storing all data but not revenue data

Tags: google-analytics

I work on a website that sells some online courses and I prepared everything to send data to google analytics via GTM, but I've been having a problem recently that I can't find a solution.

On every e-commerce related event present on the website. The "items" information is being sent (since I can see which items are the most sold). But Analytics apparently isn't receiving the price information from each item since on my reports the Revenue for each item is 0. But the revenue for the purchases in general is being received correctly, the problem is only on the item level.

These are the parameters being sent to event as seen on our GTM:

```
[
  {name: "currency", value: "EUR"},
  {
    name: "items",
    value: [
      {
        item_name: "equivalencia-medica-Ginecologia",
        price: "64.99",
        quantity: "1",
        currency: "EUR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {name: "value", value: "64.99"}
]
```

When I use Analytics DebugView and try to add an item to the cart, I do receive the `add_to_cart` event, but it only shows the "currency" and "value" parameters. The "items" parameter is nowhere to be found.

Any ideas why every possible data is being stored but not the price of the items? Please comment if more code needed.

Answer (score 0):

try removing quotes `price: 64.99` . Try following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#add_or_remove_an_item_from_a_shopping_cart)